# Finding a Matrix B by knowing its Kernel is the Image of Matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: The problem:]

[image]

I understand how to find the image($A$). The basis of Im($A$) would be the first two columns of the matrix $A$ (given the two leading 1's in ref are in the first and second columns).

So the $\text{Ker}(B) = [1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4]$

But I do not get how to find $B$ based on its kernel? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you learned about changes of basis or matrix similarity?

Comment: Yes we have learned both @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long sort of approach to the problem.  First, note that $\mathcal B = \{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(1,1,1,1),(1,2,3,4)\}$ forms a basis of $\Bbb R^4$.  Let $\mathcal A$ denote the standard basis.  $B$ will answer the question if it satisfies
$$
[B]_{\mathcal A \to \mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0}
$$
Now, it's enough to use this matrix to find $[B]_{\mathcal A \to \mathcal A}$, which is to say the standard matrix $B$.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. A (numerically) reliable way is to use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to construct the orthogonal projection $Q$ onto the span of your two vectors. Then $B = I - QQ^T$ will serve your purpose.

Comment: We haven't learned Gram-Schmidt yet, can you describe another method?